# Shadow overlay changes color

Tags: html, css, colors

I have this similar case, does anyone know how can I bring the outter space have the color of #f5f8f8, but without removing the shadow. For example I tried different colors that will make look like #f5f8f8 when it has shadow but I can't make the correct one. Anyone any ideas how should I make the right color which with the shadow above will look like #f5f8f8?

```css
.outter {
  background: #f5f8f8
}

.inner {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgb(155 155 155 / 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
  Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can handle these things with eyedropper in browser’s developer tools.

Comment: Do you want rgb() for #f5f8f8?

Comment: I need a color that with that shadow overlay will make #f5f8f8